# How to run bundle install with rvm installed using rvm1-ansible role

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ansible, rvm

I installed rvm using rv1-ansible role:

```
- hosts: all
  remote_user: deploy

  roles:
    - { role: rvm_io.ruby,
        tags: ruby,
        rvm1_rubies: ['ruby-2.4.0'],
        rvm1_user: 'deploy'
      }
```

Now I would like to run bundle install inside application directory:

```
- hosts: all
  remote_user: deploy

  tasks:
    - name: Clone git repository
      git:
        dest: /home/deploy/public_html/app_name
        repo: git@github.com:user/app_name.git

    - name: Bundle install
      bundler: 
        state: present
        chdir: /home/deploy/public_html/app_name
        executable: ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/bin/bundle
```

But get error:
`"/usr/bin/env: 'ruby_executable_hooks': No such file or directory"`

Any idea how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to do a root install - installing as a specific user does not work. Little bit of info why [here](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/4974#issuecomment-28915252) - Ansible is not logging in to run commands so doesn't pick up user-specific RVM stuff. By installing globally, `rvm` and `bundler` and all the other crap I don't know about which you need on the path is available on the path.

Example config installing ruby system wide ripped right from the `rvm1-ansible` docs:

```
- name: Configure servers with ruby support system wide
  hosts: all
  roles:
    - { role: rvm_io.ruby,
        tags: ruby,
        become: yes,

        rvm1_rubies: ['ruby-2.2.5','ruby-2.3.1'],
        rvm1_install_flags: '--auto-dotfiles',     # Remove --user-install from defaults
        rvm1_install_path: /usr/local/rvm,         # Set to system location
        rvm1_user: root                            # Need root account to access system location
      }
```